# Service might not be initialized

Tags: java, spring-boot, service

I have copied the class below from another projet, and I am getting error in the imported project, reading EcrionService might not be initialized as in attached image, what puzzels me is that it works fine in the project I imported from showing in image from project imported from:

[eservice might not be initialized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrrLY.png)

[image from project imported from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXSV9.png)

Comment: Yes compiler is correct, you haven't initialized the variable. Either you need to initialize ith `new` or looks like you need to Autowire it. Check in imported project, it will be initialized.

Comment: Please provide the source code next time as text and not as attached image.

Comment: @PradeepSimha I have attached the image of the project in which it is not initialised but it works just fine.....I called it image from project imported from in the attached.....

Comment: The `@AllArgsConstructor` will provide the neccessary constructor to initialize the final variable. Check Project Lombok: https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/AllArgsConstructor.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you declare your variable `ecrionService` as `final`, you need a constructor that initializes this variable or you should initialize the variable in-place.

```
private final EcrionService ecrionService = new EcrionService(...);
```

or in a constructor:

```
private final EcrionService ecrionService;

public TransformToListClass() {
  ecrionService = new EcrionService(...);
}
```

or you can simply provided the `EcrionService` to the constructor:

```
private final EcrionService ecrionService;

public TransformToListClass(EcrionService ecrionService) {
  this.ecrionService = ecrionService;
}
```